# Get "...kernel_require.rb:120:in `require': cannot load such file" error when I am trying to run my TC

Tags: ruby, capybara

I am trying to set my test environment up on the c9.io cloud. I used project that successfully work on Windows. But on this c9.io cloud (Linux operation system) I get

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in `require':
cannot load such file -- ..//Test_helpers//login_helper (LoadError)
```

error when I am trying to run my TC.

My project is here: 
https://github.com/kay4444/remote_tc/blob/master/rails_helper.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be requiring './Test_helpers/login_helper'  not ..//Test_helpers/loging_helper

Comment: Yes, looks like it was the issue. Thanks a lot!